# Multi Condition Array With DateValue

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm looking to create an Array Formula in Google Sheets that checks if two dates are within certain time periods.

Currently, I am using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(DATEVALUE($B3:$B)-DATEVALUE($A3:$A)<E2,TRUE,FALSE),"")
```

Which is giving me the following results:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxDeP.jpg]

The issue is that if a value is True within 90 days, it remains true within 7300 days. I would like each column to be exclusive to its current period. I had hoped the following would work, however it just makes everything to True.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(DATEVALUE($B3:$B)-DATEVALUE($A3:$A)<90 & DATEVALUE($B3:$B)-DATEVALUE($A3:$A)>1095,TRUE,FALSE),""))
```

Anyone know if there is a way for this to work? I appreciate it a ton.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vPF2O98c-VA60E9GReK7hhsEXwAMzeGvZI2NfZT3mRo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,{DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)<C2, 
   (DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)>=C2)*(DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)<D2)=1,
   (DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)>=D2)*(DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)<E2)=1,
   (DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)>=E2)*(DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)<F2)=1}))
```

[image: 0]